# How to handle exceptions in both main thread and sub threads to safely use ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have a module of functions that basically look like this:

```
import concurrent.futures as cf
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm
from typing import List, Optional

def tqdm_as_completed_results(fs: Iterable[cf.Future], executor: cf.ThreadPoolExecutor, 
                              timeout: Optional[float] = None, **tqdm_kwargs):
    # Here I do some patching of tqdm
    return (f.result() for f in tqdm(cf.as_completed(fs, timeout=timeout), **tqdm_kwargs))

def load_data(chunks: List[List[str]]) -> pd.DataFrame:
     with cf.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
          results = tqdm_as_completed_results(
              (executor.submit(my_func, codes=chunk) for chunk in chunks),
              total=len(chunks)
          )
          res_df = pd.concat(to_df(r) for r in results)
     return res_df
```

And I noticed that some results are missing from the output of `load_data` and I've found that the python doc for `ThreadPoolExecutor` explicitly states:

> All threads enqueued to ThreadPoolExecutor will be joined before the
> interpreter can exit. Note that the exit handler which does this is
> executed before any exit handlers added using atexit. This means
> exceptions in the main thread must be caught and handled in order to
> signal threads to exit gracefully. **For this reason, it is recommended
> that ThreadPoolExecutor not be used for long-running tasks**.

I highly doubt that what is described here is indeed what is happening in my code since it has multiple complex components that takes a long time to run (up to 1h).

But I have no idea how can I handle this, i.e, safely handle both, exceptions in the main thread and exceptions in the sub threads so that no exception ever goes unnoticed or silent.

Your help is greatly appreciated!